# Google search results defaults to us site instead of .com site

Tags: magento2, seo, sitemaps

We have set up a multi regional website in magento with country specific subfolders for different regions.  It has geo location based automatic redirection in place and everything works fine. But when we search in google, the google search results shows /us based links instead of /row or .com/ . We have site map files set up for each region separately